# Why would you set default parameters like this in a javascript class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In looking at an article on javascript classes, the author uses this syntax:

```
class GuitarAmp {
    constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}) {
     Object.assign(this, {
      cabinet, distortion, volume
     });
   }
}
```

What is the purpose of the `= {}` bit in the constructor parameter listing?  Aren't we setting default parameters for `cabinet`, `distortion` and `volume`?

Comment: It's setting a default if you don't supply *any* arguments i.e object

Comment: you should google or MDN ,shouldn't ask here before searching

Comment: @xianshenglu May I ask what you'd recommend I search on for a question like this?  'What does = {} mean in a constructor?' wouldn't get many valid results.

Comment: I believe it's saying that if an object is passed, those are the default values (for cabinet, distortion, volume) if those individual properties are not declared within the object, and if no parameter is supplied to the function, the default is the empty object {}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It lets you call `GuitarAmp` without any parameters, and will provide a default parameter of `{}` instead - whose destructured properties will then get default-assigned properly. Otherwise, if the function is called without any parameters, it will result in an error:

```js
class GuitarAmp1 {
    constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}) {
      console.log(cabinet);
   }
}
class GuitarAmp2 {
    constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' }) {
      console.log(cabinet);
   }
}
new GuitarAmp1();
new GuitarAmp2();
```

This default-parameter-deconstruction pattern can be used for any function, whether it's a constructor or not.